# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found IOS 12 but launches still in IOS 11, xcode 10

Tags: xcode, ionic3, ios12

this is driving me insane. I updated my device to IOS 12, and my xcode to v10. when I try to test it, it gives me the error stated in the heading.

then I inserted another device that uses ios 11 still, and in that device it launches with no problems.

Image of error

[image]

please help guys. I have already tried deleting the everything from provisional Profiles and downloading manual profiles from xcode, it still gives me this error on ios 12.

Answer (score 15):

I was having a similar issue, and it started when I updated my Xcode 9 to Xcode 10.

The same error:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

However, it fails to build on a device that runs on iOS 11. I can build on a simulator or even archive and deploy to AppStore, no matter the iOS version I set on the deployment target.

I was reading the update notes for the Xcode 10 and noticed the following:

> Build Performance
>
> - New build system improves performance and is enabled by default for all projects

I was ready to downgrade my Xcode, but as a last resort I went to "File/Project Settings" and selected "Legacy Build System" from the dropdown.
Now it builds with no issues.
And yes, I'm using the Ionic3 framework too.

Comment: you are a champ! thank your for this solution, it sorted me out. much appreciation

Comment: Mind marking the answer as a accepted?
I've been using stackoverflow for years, and wanted to comment on some issues, and just noticed that I lack the reputation for it.